# The connection for this site is not secure. localhost sent an invalid response. Try running Windows Network Diagnostics. ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Tags: visual-studio, ssl, migration

When I run my .NET Web Application project in VS 2019, I get the following error:
The connection for this site is not secure. localhost sent an invalid response. Try running Windows Network Diagnostics. ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR.

Any errors in the code could cause this issue?

[Click here to see the Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YnojH.png)

Answer (score 3):

1. Open this link in edge browser:
   edge://net-internals/#hsts
2. Scroll to the bottom where it says Delete domain security policies and enter "localhost" and delete.
3. Reopen localhost:3000/

Problem should be resolved! Goodluck.